# VB: how to get the index(es) of an array element if used in For Each

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

i have the following VB Script written in an .asp file

```
Dim myArr(5, 6) '// a 6 * 7 array

For i = LBound(myArr, 1) to UBound(myArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(myArr, 1) to UBound(myArr, 1)
        myArr(i, j) = "i:" & i & ", j:" & j
    next
next

Dim i
i = 0

For Each k In myArr
    Response.Write("i:" & i ", k:" & k & "<br>")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

using For Each i can iterate through all the array items,
and the question is how can i get the index for each dimension ?

for example: how can i get k index after 10th loop that is 2 and 4 ?

Comment: How about just not using `For Each`?  Please indicate why `For Each` is prefered over `For .. To`

Comment: oh sorry, i answered already @cm-kanode,
it's because every time my initial array has different number of dimensions and size !

Comment: An interesting problem there are a couple of ways to do this...

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Is that just cruelty, an attempty to motivate all contributors to clarify and correct their postings, or a promise to replace the dots by good ideas/code?

Comment: @Ekkehard: Its a "I'm working on an answer but I actually have a life and a job so I'll have to fit it in when I can unless some other clever clogs wants to beat me to it" comment.

Comment: @armen -1 for still not disclosing relevant aspects of the problem (source of data, operations to be done in the For Each loop) and for letting both i and j loop over the range of the first dimension.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner i'm looking for a solution, for an academic research about arrays and and their flexibility in different programming languages. i'm not chasing the "goodies" of this portal. not even interested about reputation and badges ( discovered their meaning just yesterday ) ` .) `

Comment: @armen I'm interested in 'good' questions and answers. SO's way of ensuring the quality of contributions is to let people vote (cf. my answer for my ambivalent opinion on that). As no contribution can be 'good' if it contains errors or surpasses a 'certain' amount of vagueness, everybody observing such a flaw should down vote and - to make this act usefull - point it out/justify the critique. BTW: NOT hedging your bets by classifying perfectly valid feartures of a language "unorthodox" may be a more academic procedure.

Answer (score 2):

**Useful info number 1**

First of consider this bit of VBS:

```
Option Explicit
Dim aaa(1,1,1)

Dim s : s = ""

Dim i, j, k
For i = LBound(aaa, 3) To UBound(aaa, 3)
    For j = LBound(aaa, 2) To UBound(aaa, 2)
        For k = LBound(aaa, 1) To UBound(aaa, 1)
            aaa(k, j, i) =  4 * i + 2 * j + k
        Next
    Next
Next

Dim x
For Each x in aaa
    s = s + CStr(x) + " : "
Next

MsgBox s
```

This returns "0 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7 :"  which looks good, but note the order of indexers in the inner assignment `aaa(k, j, i)`.  If we were to use the more natural `aaa(i, j, k)` we'd see what appears to us to be a jubbled order returned.  Thats because we assume that the left most indexer is the most significant but it isn't its the least significant.

Where bounds start at 0 then for the first dimension all the values in index 0..N are held contigiously where the other dimensions are 0.  Then with the next dimension at 1, the next set of 0..N members of the first dimension follow and so on.

**Useful info number 2**

Given an array of unknown number of dimensions the following code returns the count of dimensions:

```
Function GetNumberOfDimensions(arr)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i

    For i = 1 To 60000
        LBound arr, i
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            GetNumberOfDimensions = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

**Solution**

Given an array construct like this.

```
Dim arr(3,3,3)

Dim s : s = ""

Dim i, j, k
For i = LBound(arr, 3) To UBound(arr, 3)
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        For k = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(k, j, i) =  16 * i + 4 * j + k
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Here is some code that is able to determine the set of indices for each item in an array of arbitary dimensions and sizes.

```
Dim dimCount : dimCount = GetNumberOfDimensions(arr)
Redim dimSizes(dimCount - 1)

For i = 1 To dimCount
    dimSizes(i - 1) = UBound(arr, i) - LBound(arr, i) + 1
Next

Dim index : index = 0
Dim item
For Each item in arr

    s = "(" 
    Dim indexValue, dimIndex
    indexValue = index
    For dimIndex = 0 To dimCount - 1
        s = s + CStr((indexValue mod dimSizes(dimIndex)) - LBound(arr, dimIndex + 1)) + ", "
        indexValue = indexValue \ dimSizes(dimIndex)
    Next
    Response.Write Left(s, Len(s) - 2) + ") = " + Cstr(item) + "<br />"
    index = index + 1
Next
```

An interesting acedemic exercise, not sure how useful it is.

Comment: it's very useful, but since I'm doing a research, I can't rely on GetNumberOfDimensions() because it uses an unorthodox way ( `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` ) to get the dimension.
thank you for your time !

Comment: @armen: Well I'm not sure how one defines "orthodox" in the first place but the bottom line is that in VBScript the approach I've demonstrated is the __only__ way to achieve your apparent goal.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones -1 because you use the range of the first dimension (i) to index into the third dimension of the array.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Well spotted code corrected, disappointed about the downvote, bad form when you have your own answer present in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones --1 because *now* the error is removed. As I understand votes, they (should) reflect the quality of an answer which is completely independent of who else contributes what.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. For each is defined to iterate over objects without having to know the amount of objects (as defined in the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface) at the moment the next object is returned (making multithreading possible).

It is also not specified that you'll receive your objects in exact the same order as you put them (although, I never experienced an other order for arrays), that depends on the Enumerator Interface object that is specified for the collection.

Fortunately, there are other tricks to do what you want, but the implementation depends on the problem you are trying to solve.
For example, you can use an array with arrays, the ArrayList class from System.Collections.ArrayList or create an own class where you store your values or objects.

**Please note:** There are some discussions about this correctness of this answer, see the comments below. I'll study the subject and will share any relevant experiences I got from them.

Comment: The OP is asking about VBScript, not VB.NET.

Comment: @Lumi I was aware of that, but did not make that very clear: If you are refering to IEnumerable, I tried to explain the underlying mechanism VBScript is using and why the `for each` construct is working as it does. If you are hinting to the ArrayList object: That can be used as a COM object by using `Set myAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`

Comment: Alright, I guess this additional information makes it +1 then. :)

Comment: This answer is wrong. All VBScript arrays can be looped over with For Each. For one-dimensional arrays this is trivial/a truism/proven by tons of code; for multi-dimensional ones, the collections decides which elements to present in which order (but never in order of entry). [Upvoters should consider their verdict, because now the anwser is dangerous]

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - I don't understand the OP's question, and this answer by @AutomatedChaos also doesn't make much sense to me (the bit on "multithreading"), but his additional **comment** about `Set myAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")` has taught me that there is a dynamic array possibility in VBScript without resorting to `ReDim`, and I tested it and it works, so that's a +1 from my (arguably limited) perspective on VBScript. By the way, AutoChaos doesn't appear to be dispute that you can loop over all arrays using `For Each` in VBScript.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos -1 because of wrong (For Each works ok with non-live collections, no order of entry for arrays) or irrelevant (.ArrayList isn't multi-demensional) info.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for letting me know why, I should study the subject somewhat deeper (put a note on the answer). I am very familiar with VBScript, but a little new with .NET (and terminology). On the other hand, you _could_ use an arraylist, but the same way as you could use an array of arrays. I put that in the answer because the asker wanted a method to add items in an array without knowing the dimensions at forehand.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos sorry for the nitpicking, but: the op armen hinted at was 'get the index', not "add". I'm the first to say that your both ideas (using objects to store positional info, using arrays of arrays (no problem to get the dimensions (exactly 1)  for those)) are usefull if we nail down/ignore the vague/unreasonable constraints armen stated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper object like this:

```
Option Explicit
dim myArr(5,6) 
dim i, j, k

For i = LBound(myArr, 1) to UBound(myArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(myArr, 2) to UBound(myArr, 2)    
        Set myArr(i, j) = [new LookupObject]("i:" & i & ", j:" & j, i, j)
    next
next

For Each k In myArr
    Response.Write("This is k:" & k & "<br>")
    Response.Write("i index of k: " & k.I & "<br>")
    Response.Write("j index of k: " & k.J & "<br>")
Next

Public Function [new LookupObject](value, i, j)
    Set [new LookupObject] = (new cls_LookupObject).Init(value, i, j)
End Function

Class cls_LookupObject

    Private value_, i_, j_

    Public Function Init(value, i, j)
        i_ = i
        j_ = j
        value_ = value
        Set Init = me
    End Function

    Public Default Property Get Value()
        Value = value_
    End Property

    Public Property Get I()
        I = i_
    End Property

    Public Property Get J()
        J = j_
    End Property

End Class
```

DISCLAIMER: As I created this code on a non Windows machine, I couldn't test it. You could find some syntax or design errors. The naming is not very great, but this way it sticks more to your concept.

Although, it seems you are searching for a simple solution. Not one that will introduce more 'challenges': When you want to pass around values in the array that keep their internal indices, you need to `Set` them instead of just assigning them: this decreases portability.
And when you use objects, you need to know how Object References work in contrast to primitives, otherwise you'll get some unexpected behavior of values changing when you don't expected it.

Comment: Please note that the key to this problem is that the actual number of dimensions present in the array is not known.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos -1 because of using *Bounds of first dimension to loop over both dimensions

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner The _*Bounds of first dimension to loop over both dimensions_ is copy-paste code from the asker. I should have seen it, but it is not relevant for the solution.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos The 'natural history' of code is not relevant for its quality. Code with errors can never be a solution. Why not just correct the mistake (without wasting any thought on who's to blame)?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

If a person interested in how VBScript compares to other languages with regard
to arrays, foreach looping, and especially obtaining information about the
position of the element delivered by "For Each" in the collection looped over,
would pose a question like:

> How does VBScript compare to other languages with regard to arrays,
>   foreach looping, and especially obtaining information about the
>   position of the element delivered by "For Each" in the collection
>   looped over?

then a short answer would have been available long ago:

A foreach loop construct can deliver

1. a pointer (memory address) - as e.g. C/C++ does; then you have to
   de-reference the pointer to get at the element which you can even
   change; positional info is optainable by pointer arithmetic)
2. a reference (alias) (as e.g. Perl does; that allows modification,
   but obviously no computing of positions (unless the element
   accidentially contains such info))
3. a copy (as e.g. Python or VBScript do; neither modification nor
   retrieval of meta info is possible (unless some kind and clever
   souls like AutomatedChaos or AnthonyWJones work their heart out to
   implement a C/C++ alike solution by submitting a loop variable to
   DIVs and MODs resp. to design a class that allows to augment the
   plain/essential data values with meta info)

***You may safely ignore the rest of my answer; I just don't want to delete the
following text which provides some context for the discussion.***

The problem can't be dealt with, until

(1) armen describes the context of the real world problem in real world terms - where do the arrays come from, how many **dimensions** are possible, what determines the dimensional 
structure (row/column/...), which operations must be done in the For Each loop, why/how are the indices important for these operations

(2) all contributors get their selectors for the dimensions right:

```
For i = LBound(myArr, 1) to UBound(myArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(myArr, 1) to UBound(myArr, 1)
```

or variations thereof are obviously wrong/misleading. Without replacing the 1 in one line by 2, it's not clear, what row/column-structure the code is meant for.

To prove that I'm willing to contribute in a more constructive way, I throw in a function to get the (number of) dimensions for an arbitrary array:

```
Function getDimensions(aVBS)
  Dim d : d = 0
  If IsArray(aVBS) Then
     For d = 1 To 60
      On Error Resume Next
       UBound aVBS, d + 1
       If Err.Number Then Exit For
      On Error GoTo 0
     Next
  End If
  getDimensions = d
End Function ' getDimensions
```

(based on [code by M. Harris](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/browse_thread/thread/affa6109a8cb5870) and [info from the VBScript Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

**Update: Still not a solution, but some food for thought**

As armen (upto now) didn't provide the real story of his problem, I try to
give you a fictonal one (to put a context to the rows and columns and whatever
you may call the thingies in the third dimension):

Let's say there is a school - Hogmond - teaching magical programming. VBScript
is easy (but in the doghouse), so there are just three tests and students are
admitted mid term (every penny counts). JScript is harder, so you have to do the
full course and additional tests may be sheduled during the term, if pupils
prove thick. F# is more complicated, so each test has to be judged in terms of
multiple criteria, some of which may be be agreed upon during the term (the
teachers are still learning). C# is such a 'good' language, that there is just
one test.

So at the end of the term the principal - Mr. Bill 'Sauron' Stumblegates - has
an .xls, containing a sheet:

[image: scores of VBScript tests]

(Doreen was accepted during the last week of the term) and a sheet:

[image: scores of JScript tests]

(for your peace of mind, 120 additional tests are hidden); the F# results
are kept in a .txt file:

```
# Results of the F# tests
# 2 (fixed) students, 3 (fixed) test,
# 4>5 (dynamic) criteria for each test

Students  Ann       Bill
    Test  TA TB TC  TA TB TC
Criteria
  CA       1  2  3   4  5  6
  CB       7  8  9  10 11 12
  CC      13 14 15  16 17 18
  CD      19 20 21  22 23 24
# CE      25 26 27  28 29 30
```

(because I know nothing about handling three+-dimensional data in Excel).

Now we have a context to think about

1. data: it's important that Mary scored 9 for the eval test, but
   whether that info is stored in row 5 or 96 is not an inherent
   property of the data [Implies that you should think twice before you
   embark on the (taken by itself: impressive) idea of AutomatedChaos
   to create objects that combine (essential) data and (accidential)
   info about positions in a (n arbitrary) structure.]
2. processing: some computations - especially those that involve the
   whole dataset - can be done with no regard to rows or colums (e.g.
   average of all scores); some may even require a
   restructuring/reordering (e.g. median of all scores); many
   computations - all that involve selection/grouping/subsets of the
   data - just can't be done without intimate knowledge about the
   positions of the data items. armen, however, may not be interested
   in processing at all - perhaps all he needs the indices for is to
   identify the elements while displaying them. [So it's futile to
   speculate about questions like "Shouldn't Excel/the database do the
   processing?", "Will the reader be content with 'D5: 9' or does he
   whish to see 'Mary/eval: 9' - and would such info be a better
   candidate for AutomatedChaos' class?", "What good is a general 'For
   Each' based function/sub that handles arrays of every dimension, if
   assignments - a(i)=, b(i,j)=, c(i,j,k)= ... - can't be
   parameterized?"]
3. structure/layout: the choice of how you put your data into rows and
   columns is determined by convenience (vertical scrolling perfered),
   practical considerations (append new data 'at the end'), and
   technical reasons (VBScript's 'ReDim Preserve' can grow (dynamic)
   arrays in the last dimension only) - so for each layout that makes
   sense for a given context/task there are many other structures that
   are better in other circumstances (or even the first context).
   Certainly there is no 'natural order of indexers'.

Now most programmers love writing/written code more than reading stories (and
some more than to think about/plan/design code), so here is just one example
to show what different beasts (arrays, 'iterators') our pipe dream/magical
one-fits-all-dimensions 'For Each' strategy has to cope with:

Given two functions that let you cut data from Excel sheets:

```
Function getXlsRange(sSheet, sRange)
  Dim oX : Set oX = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Dim oW : Set oW = oX.Workbooks.Open(resolvePath("..\data\hogmond.xls"))
  getXlsRange = oW.Sheets(sSheet).Range(sRange).Value
  oW.Close
  oX.Quit
End Function ' getXlsRange

Function getAdoRows(sSQL)
  Dim oX : Set oX = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  oX.open Join(Array(     _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
      , "Data Source=" & resolvePath("..\data\hogmond.xls") _
      , "Extended Properties="""           _
          & Join(Array(     _
                "Excel 8.0" _
              , "HDR=No"    _
              , "IMEX=1"    _
            ), ";" )        _
          & """"            _
  ), ";")
  getAdoRows = oX.Execute(sSQL).GetRows()
  oX.Close
End Function ' getAdoRows
```

(roll your own resolvePath() function or hard code the file spec)

and a display Sub (that uses armen's very good idea to introduce a
loop counter variable):

```
Sub showAFE(sTitle, aX)
  Dim i, e
  WScript.Echo "For Each:", sTitle
  WScript.Echo "type:", VarType(aX), TypeName(aX)
  WScript.Echo "dims:", getDimensions(aX)
  WScript.Echo "lb  :", LBound(aX, 1), LBound(aX, 2)
  WScript.Echo "ub  :", UBound(aX, 1), UBound(aX, 2)
  WScript.Echo "s   :", UBound(aX, 1) - LBound(aX, 1) + 1 _
                      , UBound(aX, 2) - LBound(aX, 2) + 1
  i = 0
  For Each e In aX
      WScript.Echo i & ":", e
      i = i + 1
  Next
End Sub ' showAFE
```

you can use code like

```
  showAFE "VTA according to XlsRange:", getXlsRange("VTA", "B3:D4")
  showAFE "VTA according to AdoRows:",  getAdoRows("SELECT * FROM [VTA$B3:D4]")
```

to get your surprise of the weekend:

```
For Each: VTA according to XlsRange:
type: 8204 Variant()
dims: 2
lb  : 1 1
ub  : 2 3
s   : 2 3
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
5: 6
For Each: VTA according to AdoRows:
type: 8204 Variant()
dims: 2
lb  : 0 0
ub  : 2 1
s   : 3 2
0: 1
1: 3
2: 5
3: 2
4: 4
5: 6
```

and despair:

1. Mr. Stumblegates type system hides the fact that these two arrays
   have a very different nature (and the difference between fixed and
   dynamic arrays is ignored too)
2. You can create all kinds of arrays in VBScript as long as they are
   zero-based (no chance of creating and/or restructuring Range-born
   arrays and keep their (accidential!) one-based-ness)
3. Getting one set of data with (necessarily) one layout via two
   different methods will deliver the data with two different
   structures
4. If you ask "For Each" to enumerate the data, the sequence you get is
   determined by the iterator and not predictable (you have to
   check/experiment). (Accentuating the freedom/role of the iterator is
   the one nugget in AutomatedChaos' first answer)

[**Don't read this, if you aren't interested in/can't stand a pedantic diatribe**:

which still has a better score than AnthonyWJones' contribution, because at
least one person who admittedly has anderstood neither question nor answer
upvotes it, because of the reference to .ArrayList - which isn't relevant at all
to armen's question, because there is no way to make an ArrayList
multi-dimensional (i.e.: accessible by the equivalent of al(1,2,3)). Yes
"IEnumerable" (a pure .NET concept) and "multithread" are impressive keywords
and there are 'live' collections (e.g. oFolder.Files) that reflect 'on the fly'
modifications, but no amount of (single!)-threading will let you modify a humble
VBScript array while you loop - Mr. Stumblegates is a harsh master:

```
  Dim a : a = Array(1, 2, 3)
  Dim e
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine "no problem looping over (" & Join(a, ", ") & ")"
  For Each e In a
      WScript.Stdout.Write " " & e
  Next
  ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
  a(UBound(a)) = 4
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine "no problem growing the (dynamic) array (" & Join(a, ", ") & ")"
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine "trying to grow in loop"
  For Each e In a
      WScript.Stdout.Write " " & e
      If e = 3 Then
        On Error Resume Next
         ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
         If Err.Number Then WScript.Stdout.Write " " & Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
         a(UBound(a)) = 5
      End If
  Next
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine
```

output:

```
no problem looping over (1, 2, 3)
 1 2 3
no problem growing the (dynamic) array (1, 2, 3, 4)
trying to grow in loop
 1 2 3 This array is fixed or temporarily locked 5
```

Another elaboration of a blanket statement: Even good programmers make mistakes,
especially if they are eager to help, have to work under unfavorable conditions
(Mr. Stumblegates did his utmost to make sure that you can't use/publish VBScript
code without extensive testing), have a job and a live, or just a bad moment.

This, however, does not change the fact that some code fragments/statements are
useless or even dangerous to SO readers who - because of votes - think they have
found a solution to their problem. Quality of code/text is an essential property
of the content alone, who wrote it is just accidential. But how to be 'objective'
in a context where "Jon Doe's code" is the natural way to refer to lines like

```
for i = 0 to ubound(myArr)
         for y = 0 to ubound(myArr, 1)

    [UBound(a) and UBound(a, 1) are synonyms, so this will create havoc as soon
    as the UBounds of the different dimensions are not (accidentially) the same]
```

and votes for content are summed up under the reputations of persons? (Would SO
list millions of answers without the reputation system? Would I put less time/work
in my contributions without the points? I hope/guess not, but I'm a human too.)

So I encourage you to downvote this elaborate (at least) until I correct the
limit of 60 in my getDimensions() function. You can't hurt my feelings; I think
I'm blameless, because all I did was to rely on the docs:

> Dimensions of an array variable; up to 60 multiple dimensions may be
>   declared.

(What I'm a bit ashamed of is that I had feelings of superiority, when I looked
at the 999 or the 60000 in other people's code - as I said: I'm only human too;
and: Don't put your trust in Mr. Stumblegates, but check:

```
  Dim nDim
  For Each nDim In Array(3, 59, 60, 62, 64, 65, 70)
      ReDim aDim(nDim)
      Dim sDim : sDim = "ReDim a" & nDim & "(" & Mid(Join(aDim, ",0"), 2) & ")"
      WScript.Echo sDim
     On Error Resume Next
      Execute sDim
      If Err.Number Then WScript.Echo Err.Description
     On Error GoTo 0
  Next
```

output:

```
ReDim a3(0,0,0)
...
ReDim a64(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ReDim a65(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Subscript out of range
...
```

)

Not to conclude in destructive mode: I still hope that my harping on the topic
"bounds used in nested loops to specify indexers (especially such of different
ranges)" will magically cause a lot of code lines here to be changed in the near
future - or aren't we all students at Hogmond?

]

Comment: (1) would be better included in a comment.  (2) ought to be comments on those other contributions rather than a blanket statement.

Comment: Your update is very impressive and informative excercise for the commoners at the `VBScript tag`, unfortunately I do not not see how you are helping the questioner. And no, I will not downvote, if one has to use more than 60 dimensions, there is a bigger problem than a wrong limitation.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you told us which houses the respective students were in.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested For loops, instead of For Each

```
for i = 0 to ubound(myArr)
     for y = 0 to ubound(myArr, 2)
        ' do something here...
    next
next
```

Comment: for the current problem i prefer `For Each` because the function doesn't know the array dimensions and size of each dimension.

i know there is a way to determine an array dimension "count" using `On Error bla bla bla`, but this type of coding is out of my scope !

in my example the array has 2 dimensions `Dim myArr(5, 6)`, but every call to this function will require different dimension and size array !

Comment: qCM -1 for using the UBound of the first dimension for both i and j